# How to remove consecutive duplicate characters

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm new to R and have no background in programming. 
My problem is I have data like this:
[image]

In the "path" column, I want to remove all the consecutive duplicates like the red-framed ones in the above image. 
For example: **Organic > Paid Search > Paid Search > Paid Search > Direct > Direct > Organic** should become: **Organic > Paid Search > Direct > Organic**

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please do not share data as an image. Use `dput(head(dataset,n))` and share the output of that. Also add sample code, current and expected output. Add any available errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option based on `strsplit` and `rle`:

```
x <- c("Organic > Paid Search > Paid Search > Paid Search > Direct > Direct > Organic")
x <- trimws(strsplit(x, ">")[[1]], "both")
paste(rle(x)$values, collapse = " > ")
# output
[1] "Organic > Paid Search > Direct > Organic"
```

Using a `data.frame`, try out:

```
df <- data.frame(Path = c("Organic > Paid Search > Paid Search > Paid Search > Direct > Direct > Organic",
                          "Organic > Paid Search >  Paid Search > Direct > Organic > Direct",
                          "Organic > Organic > Paid Search > Paid Search > Direct > Direct"),
                 conversions = c(6, 5, 3), stringsAsFactors = F)
# Solution
df$Path2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$Path, ">"),
                   function(x) paste(rle(trimws(strsplit(x, ">"), "both"))$values,
                                     collapse = " > "))
df # output
                                                                           Path conversions                                             Path2
1 Organic > Paid Search > Paid Search > Paid Search > Direct > Direct > Organic           6          Organic > Paid Search > Direct > Organic
2              Organic > Paid Search >  Paid Search > Direct > Organic > Direct           5 Organic > Paid Search > Direct > Organic > Direct
3               Organic > Organic > Paid Search > Paid Search > Direct > Direct           3                    Organic > Paid Search > Direct
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: You're welcome @trangbui. For your future questions, you should consider sharing a subset of your data set, not an image as pointed out by NelsonGon. Welcome on SO ! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was my first time posting here so I didn't get used to the editor much :D